# install ruby gem (no write permissions)?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I get this error while trying to install sass
Should I use sudo before the install statement?

```
rd-macbook-pro:~ redres$ gem install css_parser
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
rd-macbook-pro:~ redres$
```

thanks, Rich

Comment: I would take the advice below and install either RVM or Rbenv.  There are just to many benefits to not do this

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use sudo or set gem path

```
mkdir -p /Users/redres/.gem/ruby/1.8
export GEM_PATH=/Users/redres/.gem/ruby/1.8
export GEM_HOME=/Users/redres/.gem/ruby/1.8
```

but i highly recommend to try using RVM https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

to install and

```
rvm requirements
```

to get further information

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using a ruby version manager (like rvm or rbenv), you'll need to use `sudo` to install on system-level.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is because you are not logged in as the root user on terminal.

If you already have root use enable on your mac in terminal type (without the $)

```
$ su
```

If you dont have root user, you need to enable it using the following steps

1. From the Apple menu choose System Preferences….
2. From the View menu choose Users & Groups.
3. Click the lock and authenticate as an administrator account.
4. Click Login Options….
5. Click the “Edit…” or “Join…” button at the bottom right.
6. Click the “Open Directory Utility…” button.
7. Click the lock in the Directory Utility window.
8. Enter an administrator account name and password, then click OK.
9. Choose Enable Root User from the Edit menu.
10. Enter the root password you wish to use in both the Password and Verify fields, then click OK.

More at the same on http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528

Atleast it works for me after getting stuck for couple of hours.